# Password-Protected Video in cPanel site won't play in Safari

Tags: safari, cpanel, password-protection, quicktime

**Summary.**  I administer a website, for which I pay a small monthly fee to have hosted on a shared server.  It has cPanel.  When I upload a video which is longer than a few seconds, and password-protect it, and try to view it in Safari as a user would, it asks for the credential, but then won't play.  If I try the same thing in Firefox, it works, and then it works in Safari for a day or so, without entering anything.  What might be going on here?

**Steps to reproduce**

• Using cPanel's File Manager, create a new directory on my site.

• In cPanel, password-protect the new directory, composing a username and password.

• Using the FTP client on my computer, upload a 4-minute .mov Quicktime movie file to this new directory.

• On my computer running Mac OS X 10.9, activate Safari 7.0 and browse to the uploaded .mov file. A sheet ***and/or*** a freestanding dialog window appears asking for Username and password.

• Enter the User name and password, once or twice.

RESULT: A Quicktime Player appears, but showing the scrubber and control strip only, no video box. It says "Loading", and hangs there forever.  Clicking the ► "play" button has no effect.

• On same Macintosh, activate Firefox (Aurora version 27) and browse to the same .mov file. Again, sheet appears asking for username and password.

• Enter username and password.

RESULT: Movie plays in Firefox.

• Reload page in Safari.

RESULT: Movie plays in Safari now, *without entering anything*.

**Further Info**

This seems to work until maybe the next day.  If I try to reload the page the next day, it won't play until I enter username and password into Firefox again.  This is apparently not related to my IP address, because whatsmyip.org is giving me the same number today as yesterday.  Also, I just tried it in Safari on my iPad Mini, entered username and password, and it worked.  But we're on the same LAN with the same gateway IP address.

[Here is a link to the protected movie](http://sheepsystems.com/engineering/protected/test/long4.mov), which I have uploaded for testing.  (It's a rip of the first 4 minutes of Apple's October 13 event.)

To test it, you'll need:    Username: test      Password: test13579

The finger most likely points at Safari, but before I give up and file a bug with Apple, can anyone take a stab at what might be going on or how to work around it?

Thanks,

Jerry Krinock

P.S.  Why I want this: I support some Mac OS X apps, and sometimes people send me their private data in a support request. I'd like to be able to make a quick video, showing them what to do with their data, and then create a protected folder for them on my server, upload the video, and send them the username and password. I know there are alternative services which can do this, but to do it on my own cPanel site is quick, convenient for both of us, and of course, no additional cost or accounts to fuss with.

Comment: It works fine on my iPad withOUT running in Firefox first.  Also works in Google Chrome, after I enable QuickTime player.

Comment: Now submitted to Apple Bug Reporter.  Problem ID 15469180.

Comment: Well, Apple has closed my bug as a duplicate of a duplicate which was originally reported around late 2010 and has priority "medium" :(  A workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing on the un-embedded video.

In Mac OS X, it plays OK in Firefox and Google Chrome, but not in Safari.  In iOS 7, it plays OK in Safari, but not in Google Chrome and not in Foxbrowser.

How did they manage that?

But it doesn't matter because I have a workaround.  [Embed the video into a professionally-crafted HTML page](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23792660?ac_cid=op123456#23792660).